# Laravel localization with resource method

Tags: laravel, localization, resources

I just got stuck creating routes with localization.

The language should be read from the URL:
domain/en/cars/
domain/fr/cars/
domain/en/cars/create
domain/fr/cars/edit
...

I use the resource method to create the routes:
Route::resource('cars','CarsController');

Similar to Route::get, how can I use placeholders in the URL to specify the language?

I don't want to start with changing all routes to "Route::get". Or is there a better way to implement localization?

Answer (score 0):

Route `resources` declaration also allows you to specify routes placeholders the way you would in a `get` route declaration

```
Route::resource("/domain/{language}/cars", "CarsController");
```

and within your CarsController, use it as follows

```
class CarsController
{
    public index ($language)
    {
        App::setLocale($language);
        ...
    }

    public show ($language, $id)
    { ... }
}
```

Or better still

```
class CarsController
{
    public __construct ()
    {
        if ($currentRoute = Route::current()) {
            $language = $currentRoute->getParameter('language');
            App::setLocale($language);
        }
        // ...
    }

    public show ($language, $id)
    { ... }

    public show ($language, $id)
    { ... }
}
```

Edit: Added the setting of locale. in both the constructor and in each Controller method

Comment: And how do I get the automatism with the {{ __('file.text') }} function within Blade?

Comment: You'll have to set the Locale. I've update the answer.

Comment: Hey, I KNOW that your answer is the right one.. but.. I'm afraid there's one piece missing: 

I got following error: Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $language ]] in class App\Http\Controllers\CarsController


Where is it missing?

Comment: An oversight from me. I've added the following. I've updated the constructor method. It is a cleaner way to use it and it also fixes the issue for you.

Comment: To add to that, you might later look into using a middleware instead of the Controller's constructor. That way, it'll be make it easier to use in other controllers as well.

Comment: Your example with $language = Route::current()->... works in the browser. But in artisan functions like "route:list" I got an  "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to a member function parameter() on null" error. I don't understand this, because in the browser-frontend everything is okay and the parameter method returns the correct string-value.

Comment: That is an error I haven't experienced. I will try it again and find a fix for you.

Comment: @Gira I have update my answer. The reason for the error is: routes are not attempted or accessed when you call `php artisan route:list` the same way they would when you access the application via HTTP. The fix I added is to check if there is a current route being requested for, if there's one, then set the scope, else continue with application process.